# Regular Expression for get data between \ (backslash) and first . (dot)

Tags: regex, pdf, syntax, format, calibre

I`m trying to setup my calibre (calibre-ebook.com) to automatic get data from imported pdf files into library.
Usually i name my files this way:

Author. Title. Local. Publisher. Published. ISBN.pdf

Example:

C:\Test\RANCIÊRE, Jacques. O mestre ignorante. Belo Horizonte. Autêntica. 2010. 978-85-7526-045-6.pdf

I`m stuck trying get the first paramenter: Author, using the regex:

```
([^\\]+)\.
```

I`m getting this value:

*RANCIÊRE, Jacques. O mestre ignorante. Belo Horizonte. Autêntica. 2010. 978-85-7526-045-6*

Since regex read from left to right isn`t to stop on first dot (.) from .?

The desired value on this example is:

**RANCIÊRE, Jacques**

Any hint for the other fields? Example for Title the desired value is:

**O mestre ignorante**

Thanks in advice!!!

Comment: Is the folder name known? is it always one level down? if not, I suggest to use a more complex regex that will capture Drive (i.e. C) then Path, then the Filename. Then in a separate regex process Filename

Comment: I`m not sure how the program work, in the "Settings" / "Adding Books" there an place where i need inform the full path of one file to test, and set the regular expression, for the Author name the program use this: (?P<title>My_Regular_Expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^.+?\.` will get you the `C:\Test\RANCIÊRE, Jacques.`

it means get the all characters before the first dot.

if you want only `RANCIÊRE, Jacques` than use:

```
(?!(.*\\))(.+?\.)
```

will give you `RANCIÊRE, Jacques.`

Comment: I see this while was testing many other syntax (i`m using the rubular.com to test and need get only one value / match), but i need get specific data, for the Author in this example the result need be: RANCIÊRE, Jacques

Comment: but if you need split string on few different substring, regexp not will work here. try use simple `String.split()`

Comment: Yup i see, but i don`t need the "C:\Test\" data, only the Author name ;)

Comment: I`m reading the Python documentation for see how the str.split works ;)

Comment: @Wisdown could you expalain what you really want? i could help you with python

Comment: I`m willing setup an default regex for import my pdfs to library inside of the program "calibre". Change the test syntax to: "C:\Test\RANCIÊRE, Jacques. O mestre ignorante. Autêntica. 978-85-7526-045-6.pdf" and using this code from @mc10 inside of "calibre": "(?P<author>([^\\]+?)\.)(?P<title>([^\\]+?)\.)(?P<publisher>([^\\]+?)\.)" works pretty well, but if i add one more statement to get the ISBN all previus data get messed, example: (?P<isbn>([^\\]+?)\.)

Answer (score 0):

Regex capturing is greedy, meaning it tries to get the largest match as possible. Try the non-greedy version:

```
([^\\]+?)\.
```

Note the only difference is the addition of a `?`.

Afterwards, you should be able to retrieve the author's name ("RANCIÊRE, Jacques") with just `\1`.

Comment: On this example i get 6 Match possible groups:

Match 1
RANCIÊRE, Jacques

Match 2
O mestre ignorante

Match 3
Belo Horizonte

Match 4
Autêntica

Match 5
2010

Match 6
978-85-7526-045-6

I need get only one value (since i will pass this for an fuction of the calibre program), for the author need be the first match 1:

RANCIÊRE, Jacques

There any way to select the desired match groups like an array?
If the matches group become an array:

["RANCIÊRE, Jacques", "O mestre ignorante", "Belo Horizonte", "Autêntica", "2010", "978-85-7526-045-6"]

I`m willing get the:

Array[0]

Tested on
rubular.com